# Creating Sublime Text 3 Snippets for CSS Selectors

Tags: css, sublimetext3, css-selectors, emmet

I'm using ST3 and trying to create a snippet to quickly output the first child selector. I have saved the file with a `.sublime-snippet` extension in the Packages/User location. My snippet code:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
:first-child {}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>first</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.css</scope>
    <description>first-child</description>
</snippet>
```

So when I type `div` and then the `tabTrigger` text, the new snippet does not appear in a list or when I press the Tab key. What do I have to do to get it working?

( Note: I've noticed that it works only inside curly braces but this is useless as it needs to work for the CSS selectors which are outside the braces! )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t easily combine ST and Emmet snippets in CSS due to some technical problems. As a workaround, you can create snippets right in Emmet:

- http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/
- https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#extensions-support

Answer (score 2):

There is a way and it is as follows (using a Mac with OS X):

1) Download and install [Package Resource Viewer](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer)

2) Open the Command Palette within ST3 (accessed typing Command+Shift+P in Mac, or Ctrl+Shift+P in Windows)

3) Type `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package`

4) Select the `CSS` option

5) Now in the menu go to `Sublime Text / Preferences / Browse Packages` (a folder window will pop up)

6) Go to the `CSS` folder within the `Packages` folder

7) Select the file named `Completion Rules.tmPreferences` and drag it to ST3 so that it opens it

8) One line says `<string>source.css meta.selector</string>`. What you have to do is to delete `source.css meta.selector`, so that you now have `<string></string>`

9) Save

10) Quit ST3 and re-open it

Now you are done and your snippet should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where Sublime Text 3 was not expanding my snippets in CSS, they would work with a tab inside Sass or Scss files, but not CSS. They would expand, however, by pressing Ctrl+Space (on Mac)

The above answer, updating the CSS package, broke my intelliSense (autocomplete no longer worked)
However leaving `<string>source.css</string>` and simply removing `meta.selector` fixed both issues for me